# how to insert some value to laravel cookie using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-4

I have a very very large forms in my website i want that 
if someone come on my website's page fill any form and leave it without submitting data it will saved on browser cookie and i can access this in laravel using cookie::get() method.

So in this way when user come back to my page i can redirect it withInput() method of laravel so In this way i didn't need any javascript method for filling input field.

I am able to save my data to cookie but can't access to my data from Laravel cookie::get() mehtod.

Comment: can you so some of your code s??

Comment: there isn't any thing to show because i added cookie using javascript and laravel save cookie with some type encryption i need to decode that encryption using javascript so in this way i wiil be able to save cookie with laravel enryption and will be able to get its value using php code(laravel code)